# How to make horizontal space between checkbox

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
.input[type="radio"] {
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="num" value="1"><label>Label1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="num" value="2"><label>Label2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="num" value="3"><label>Label3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="num" value="4"><label>Label4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="num" value="5"><label>Label5</label>
</div>
```

How do I change the horizontal spacing between the radio button and the text? I'd like the text to be further to the radio button.

Comment: they should all have the same name

Comment: and the selector should be `input[type="radio"] `

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your consideration. ```Input[type="radio"]``` does nothing

Comment: remove the uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

The `name` must be the same for all radio buttons to toggle only one of them.

The class sets the right margin to 0.

And the `id` on the input is linked with the `for` attribute on the label so you can toggle the radio button by clicking the label too.

```css
.mr0 {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="label" value="1" class="mr0" id="1"><label for="1">Label1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="label" value="2" class="mr0" id="2"><label for="2">Label2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="label" value="3" class="mr0" id="3"><label for="3">Label3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="label" value="4" class="mr0" id="4"><label for="4">Label4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="label" value="5" class="mr0" id="5"><label for="5">Label5</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I change margin-right value if I want more space?

Comment: Yes it will add more space between the radio button and its label.